# MS TFS 2015 mandatory linking between work items

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

In TFS there is possibility to link work items between each other - for example PBIs to Features, or Impediments. Does anybody know - how to make these links mandatory, so for example it will be not possible to save PBI if it was not linked to feature?

I'm using TFS2015 on premises.

Answer (score 1):

According to the request, you need to set the Required rule for the links control, but as far as I know the default Links control not support Required rule.

So, as workaround you can add a hidden field, then set '**Required**' rule for the hidden field, thus it will prompt that you need to link to Features or other workitems when you save the PBI without any linked workitems.

Here is the example. You could add field called **Links**, which is hidden field and it would have the following syntax:

```
<FIELD  name="Links" refname="lc.RelatedWorkItems" type="Integer">
    <WHEN field="System.RelatedLinkCount" value="0">
       <REQUIRED />
    </WHEN>
    <WHENNOT value="0" field="System.RelatedLinkCount">
       <DEFAULT from="field" field="System.RelatedLinkCount" />
    </WHENNOT>
    <HELPTEXT>This is a hidden/internal field that will help to force the user to associate the work items.</HELPTEXT>
</FIELD>
```

[image]

Comment: @BorisPevzner I checked this, it can achieve your requirement, please reference the screenshot, the PBI can not be saved without link work items.

Comment: Yes, it is working perfectly! Next question - how can I make requirements more strict? - e.g. it will have to be to save PBI only in case 1 feature and 1 impediment are linked, if 2 features are linked and 0 impediments then it should not be possible to save PBI.

Comment: @BorisPevzner You cannot specify more than one parent link (Feature link here) for the PBI,the default process already restrict it. What's the impediments mean? Anyway, you can specify the link types to restrict which type of work items can be linked to the PBI. Please see https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/define-link-controls for more information.

Comment: Impediment is another work item type, like PBI or Bug. My idea is to create new work item type and make following limitation - it will be allowed to save it only if one bug and one impediment are linked to this item, in any other case it will be not possible to save this work item.

Comment: @BorisPevznerb As far as I know, it's difficult to achieve that, we can only restrict the linked work item types to bug and impediment.